# How do I get annotate variable in view to display data on django template?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I get annotate to display data on django template when I load the pastry_list.html page? I have a variable set to the annotate line in views.py. I have a for loop running through the variable in template. Am I missing something or doing something wrong? For some reason it seems that the template is not recognizing the views.py variable. Thanks.

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.utils import timezone
 from django.urls import reverse
 from collections import OrderedDict

class IntegerRangeField(models.IntegerField):
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, min_value=None, 
max_value=None, **kwargs):
    self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
    models.IntegerField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    defaults = {'min_value': self.min_value, 
'max_value':self.max_value}
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(IntegerRangeField, self).formfield(**defaults)

class Pastry(models.Model):
CHOICES_DICT = OrderedDict((
    ("Muffin", "Muffin"),
    ("Cupcake", "Cupcake"),
    ("Brownie", "Brownie"),
    ("Cake", "Cake"),
    ("Fruit Tart", "Fruit Tart")
))
pastry = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="muffin",   
choices=CHOICES_DICT.items())
vote = IntegerRangeField(default=1, min_value=1, max_value=1)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("pastry_detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return self.pastry


VIEWS.PY
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                              DetailView,CreateView,
                              UpdateView,DeleteView)
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Pastry
from myapp.forms import PastryForm
from django.db.models import F


ps = Pastry.objects.values('pastry').annotate(total=Count('pastry'))

class PollsListView(ListView):
model = Pastry

def get_queryset(self):
    return Pastry.objects.all()

class PollsDetailView(DetailView):
model = Pastry

class PollsCreateView(CreateView):
success_url = reverse_lazy('pastry_list')
form_class = PastryForm
model = Pastry

class PollsUpdateView(UpdateView):
success_url = reverse_lazy('pastry_list')
form_class = PastryForm
model = Pastry


class PollsDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = Pastry
success_url = reverse_lazy('pastry_list')

pastry_list.html  (template) 
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">

<a href="{% url 'pastry_new' %}">New Poll</a>
<h1>Voting for the favorite pastry</h1>

{% for p in ps %}
 {% for k, v in p.items %}
   {{v}}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for pastry in pastry_list %}
    <div class="pastry">
        <h3><a href="{% url 'pastry_detail' pk=pastry.pk %}">
  {{ pastry.pastry }}</a></h3>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

 </div>

  {% endblock %}


FORMS.PY
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Pastry
from django.forms import ModelForm

class PastryForm(ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = Pastry
    fields = ['pastry', 'vote']

 PASTRY_FORM.HTML
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% load widget_tweaks %}
 {% block content %}
 <div class="jumbotron">
 <h1>New Poll</h1>
 <form class="post-form" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Personally I would just record each vote as a new row. Then you can use `annotate` and `Sum` to group the categories and their totals. For example as a property method.

Comment: I tried to add this to my views.py pastrys = Pastry.objects.values('pastry').aggregate(total=Sum('vote'))
and I added this to my pastry_list.html template
<p>Muffins: {% for pastry in pastrys %}
  {{ pastry.pastry }} total: {{ pastry.total }}
{% endfor %}
But it is not displaying any data. Can you advise me where I went wrong? Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you use `pdb` to inspect your vars, to see what that queryset actually returns. Make sure you have data in your table. And you probably wanna use `annotate` instead of `aggregate`.

Comment: I tried with pdb but can't find the error. I changed it to this but still doesn't work. Is it because my field has choices? In views.py I only have this line as a variable ps = Pastry.objects.values('pastry').annotate(total=Count('pastry'))
In the template I have the following, but it seems it is being ignored. Am I missing something?
{% for p in ps %}
  {% for k, v in p.items %}
    {{v}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: The annotate line in views does have correct data, but somehow my template is not retrieving the data.
{'pastry': 'Brownie', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Cake', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Cupcake', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Fruit Tart', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Muffin', 'total': 2}

Comment: Looks like it's a list. So just iterate over it and access it through the dictionary keys. I.e `{{ foo.pastry }}` and `{{ foo.total }}`.